# NSDocumentDictionary: Saving NSString as file for Russian characters

Tags: ios, objective-c, utf-8, nsstring, nsdocumentdirectory

I have an editable uitextview in which the user types in Russian or English. I then save this text as a .txt file in the files directory, and read it later.

Here is the portion to save the text

```
-(IBAction)saveText:(id)sender{


    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"testing.txt"];
    [self.textBox.text writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
    NSLog(path);

}
```

There is a separate button to display this text in a popover:

```
-(IBAction)readText:(id)sender{

    NSString *documentsDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"testing.txt"];
    NSError *error = nil;
 myText = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
    NSLog(@"myText: %@", myText);
    self.textBox.text= myText;
    }
```

with this declaration in the .h file

```
NSString *myText;
```

it works fine if I only type English, but if I type Russian characters then nothing saves/displays.

So, say I type "hello" it works, but ifI then type " *some Russian phrase* " to append self.textBox.text it doesn't work.

How can I make this Russian (or UTF8/charcode) compatible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`writeToFile:atomically:` is deprecated and writes the string in the default encoding
(whatever that is, probably MacRoman). Better use

```
[self.textBox.text writeToFile:path
                    atomically:NO
                      encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding
                         error:&error];
```

to write the string UTF-8 encoded.

Comment: What Martin said. I was about to answer the same thing, but he beat me to it. 


Pay attention to the deprecated method warnings you get from the compiler. Apple generally deprecates methods for good reasons (like the fact that `writeToFile:atomically` doesn't let you specify an encoding.

Comment: Martin R and Duncan C thank you, this fixed the issue. I'll have to pay more attention to the warnings...